# How to use libraries and headers in C++ with MinGW?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glew

I want to use OpenGL GLEW library. I have the binary downloaded and its folder is in the folder with my .cpp file. My .cpp file uses `#include <eglew.h>`.

How should I format my command for MinGW to compile my .cpp file? Do I compile with the .lib file like `g++ -L./path/to/lib/file.lib test.cpp -o test` or do I do something else like link to the header files `g++ -I./path/to/headers test.cpp -o test`?

Comment: you can try: ```g++ -L./path/to/lib/file.lib -I./path/to/headers test.cpp -o test```, change your 
 include ```<eglew.h>``` to ```"eglew.h"``` may helps.

Comment: You seem to have to wrong binary. MinGW normally works with `.a`, no `.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand things maybe it's better to split compiling and linking steps.
If you get errors then you will also know in which step the problem occurs.

I'm assuming you have the following folders/files:

```
/path/to/eglew/include/GL/eglew.h
/path/to/eglew/lib/libglew32.a
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -Wall -c -o test.o test.cpp -I/path/to/eglew/include/GL
```

Linking:

```
g++ -o test.exe test.o -L/path/to/eglew/lib -lglew32
```

Though I would expect to see `#include <GL/eglew.h>` in which case the linker include flag should be `-I/path/to/eglew/include`.

Comment: It is good habit to ask for warnings from the compiler